# Manipulate expression overlaid on plot of data

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to use the `Manipulate` function in *Mathematica* and want to plot an expression over a scatterplot of (x,y) data. I can programme the `Manipulate` function, but am unable to do this on the same axes as the scatterplot - any hints much appreciated

I want to plot this data and then use `Manipulate` to visually fit a curve to the data...

The code I have written for the Manipulate function is:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[c*k*(x^(c - 1))/((1 + x^c)^(j)), {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 10}}], {c, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

and I want to include a command so the following plot is included on the axes in the manipulate environment.

The following data plot is created with:

```
ListPlot[ddata, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 0.05}}, AxesOrigin -> {-6, 0}]
```

[image: This is the scatterplot I want in the background...]

ddata is given by:

```
ddata = First@ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KwJSvA2r", "Data"];
```

Comment: I have added a plot of the data - but if I could give a complete example, I wouldn't need to ask the question!  Hope this additional data clarifies my question?

Comment: I have added the code I have written already - but I can't find the relevant commands to plot my data on the same axes as the manipulated function - does this make more sense?  (thank you for your queries)

Comment: Does this make it clearer?  I realise I will need to add a coefficient in the analytic expression to get the height of the peak correct...!  ddata is a set of 200 (x,y) data pairs...

Answer (score 2):

```
ddata = First@ToExpression@Import[
     "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KwJSvA2r", "Data"];
ddata = ddata /. {a_, b_} -> {a + 1.5, b};
backgraound = ListPlot[ddata,
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {0, 500}},
  AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{backgraound,
   Plot[r (c k (x - a)^(-1 + c) (1 + (x - a)^c)^-j), {x, 0, 5}]},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {0, 500}},
  AxesOrigin -> {-2, 0}],
 {c, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 5},
 {a, -2, 2}, {r, 30, 70}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
ddata = First@ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KwJSvA2r", "Data"];

points = ListPlot[ddata, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 100}}, Axes -> True];

Manipulate[
 Show[points, 
  Plot[c*k*(x^(c - 1))/((1 + x^c)^(j)), {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 100}}]], {c, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 5}]
```

[image]